# Parsing XML webservice and storing the data for presentation on a windows phone 7 device

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing, isolatedstorage

I'm working on an app that requires extracting data from an xml web service, then I want to store that data (images+titles+datetime ...) to display it on my app then select an item and navigate to another page that displays more info about this item.

Is there a detailed tutorial that explains the parsing and storing process clearly (with the threads) because I'm gonna need it a lot for my app.Thanks!
I usually use this method, but didn't always get me what i want:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(e.Result));
var items = from c in doc.Descendants("item")
        select new RSSitem()
        {
            Title = c.Element("title").Value,
            Photo = c.Element("img").Attribute("src").Value,
            Description = c.Element("description").Value,
            Link = c.Element("link").Value,
        };
ListBoxNews.ItemsSource = items;
```

Comment: Your question is far too vague. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I only tried to parse a xml but when i want to display it it only lists the last item, storage broblem i guess! (i'm only triying to get the data from the xml (web-service) not to create one (a web-service))

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are in over your head (based on the vague nature of your question). So I'm offering my advise to get up to speed, so you can get started and ask a question that we can help give a definitive answer to.

With WP7 and .NET you shouldn't really have to do much manual parsing of [Web Services](http://zetitle.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/wp7-connecting-to-web-services-that-uses-authentication/). You should be able to [add a Service Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/windowsphone7series/thread/E3F8BA1D-F044-4230-BD1B-7E61F93E90EA) and generate a proxy which will handle this for you. This will also generate business objects for the data returned by your service.

Once you have that done, you can look into [Windows Phone Navigation](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Navigation-in-depth--Navigation-Framework) which should help you transition between pages in your application.

Answer (score 0):

To consume web services:

```
String baseUri = “your service URI";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_downloadstringcompleted);
// event handler that will handle the ‘downloadstringsompleted’ event

       wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(baseUri));    
//   this method will download your string URI asynchronously 


}
        void wc_downloadstringcompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
        // method will get fired after URI download completes
         // writes your every code here
}
```

To parse the data:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
{  

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

To store in isolated storage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

For navigation:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml?msg=" + navigationstring, UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: But how can i store the parsed data then display the stored data?

Comment: you can use IsolatedStorage (preferrably sitesettings) to store the parsed data

Comment: I mean how can i include the Isolated Storage while parsing data?Didn't find an answer to that on [msdn-isolatedstorage] o_O'

Comment: what's your data first of all?

Comment: Actually it's a complicated RssFeed.